# Invalid date in Javascript using MomentJS

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js, momentjs

MomentJS keeps printing invalid date for the following value: `Time: '2018-01-01T00:01:01.001+01:00'`,  which is part of Object `loraContent`.

I am currently calling it like this:
`var formatted = moment(loraContent.Time, "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sss+01:00").format("hh:mm A");`

When logging `formatted` the console returns "Invalid Date"

Comment: Are you sure `Time` is defined? It works for me https://jsfiddle.net/fzphu2mv/

Comment: @Rashomon printing just Time works for me, but printing the formatted line results only into "Invalid Date"

Comment: The code you show here just works, so theres not much else to do. Maybe show us a bit more?

Comment: @Rashomon plain copying the jsfiddle you provided returns in a "Invalid date" for me. Could it be something wrong with the installation? I don't see anything else it could possibly be.

Comment: Check  your `moment` package version. Jsfiddle is using v2.5.1

Comment: @Rashomon I've installed the latest version, which seems to be 2.24.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use uppercase letters for Year, month, and day tokens ([docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)):

```js
let time = '2018-01-01T00:01:01.001+01:00'

let formatted = moment(time, "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sss+01:00").format("hh:mm A");

console.log(formatted)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Seems like v2.5.1 keeps some compatibility with lowercase.